# Systems of polynomial equations in several varibles.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, polynomials

In linear algebra in $\mathbb{R}^3$ we can describe a plane with one equation. The famous "equation of the plane". We can do a line by combining two such "equations of the plane" into a linear equation system.

Is the same thing possible to do in general with multivariate polynomials?

Example: $x^2+y^2-1$ has zeroes which are the unit circle. We could make it an inequality to be able to describe the interior of the circle, but is there some way (in general) to achieve the same thing without using inequalities? We can describe surfaces in 3D, like a cone $x^2+y^2-z^2 = 0$, but what about volumes? Like a filled in cone is easy to describe turning the above into an inequality, but would it be possible to do with equalities or equation systems?

Comment: What you're describing is algebraic geometry.

Comment: Yes as far as I know, it is. And I'm not very good at it so far, therefore the question.

Comment: Algebraic geometry is probably one of the deepest areas of mathematics. If you want to learn it I'm sure you can google "how to learn algebraic geometry", and you'll find some options. My main resources when starting were Hartshorne, Ravi Vakil's notes, and the stacks project.

Comment: Note that before you learn algebraic geometry you should make sure you have a good background in commutative algebra - that is, the study of rings, modules, fields, localization, local rings, discrete valuation rings, PID's, integral closures. You don't necessarily need to know all of it, and it's definitely possible to learn it as you need it. Just keep in mind that this will take some SERIOUS work. If you really want to learn it, just take it one small chunk at a time. Make sure you understand it, then move on to the next.

Comment: search for Gröebner basis, don't sweat

Comment: I do not aim to learn this 100% theoretically, mostly reach some level of understanding to be able to build cool stuff with it :) Thanks a lot for the feedback oxeimon.